# Passar parâmetro para um Controller C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estou aprendendo a programas em ASP.NET MVC C# e gostaria de saber como eu faço para passar um dado de uma textbox para um controller. Ou seja, eu quero digitar um valor(id) na View Index em uma textbox e quando eu clicar em Enviar ele me retorna a View Details com o id que eu digitei na view Index. Esse exemplo é ele pegar pelo o Nome, Tel e CPF através do id que eu digitar na view index. A view details esta funcionando perfeitamente, quando eu passo o id por url ele me mostra os dados da pessoa.

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewResult Details(int id )
    {
        ClienteEntity cliente = new ClienteEntity(id);
      //  var cli = cliente.FetchUsingPK(id);
        return View(cliente);
    }

}



    {
        ClienteEntity cliente = new ClienteEntity(id);
      //  var cli = cliente.FetchUsingPK(id);
        return View(cliente);
    }

}
```

View do Index

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Digite um Numero: @Html.TextBox("id")</h2>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
```

View do Details

```
<h2>Dados Do Cliente</h2>
<h2>Nome: @Model.NomeCliente</h2>
<h2>CPF: @Model.Cpf</h2>
<h2>Tel: @Model.Tel</h2>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faltaram algumas coisas:

Na sua *View* `Index`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <h2>Digite um Numero: @Html.TextBox("id")</h2>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
}
```

Isto porque você vai enviar informações para um *Controller*, então não faz sentido ter um `TextBox` sem um formulário contendo-o.

No *Controller*, adicione um método que aceite o `POST` da informação enviada, como abaixo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
    }

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        ClienteEntity cliente = new ClienteEntity(id);
      //  var cli = cliente.FetchUsingPK(id);
        return View(cliente);
    }

}


    /* Comentei esta parte porque ela não faz sentido no seu código.
    {
        ClienteEntity cliente = new ClienteEntity(id);
      //  var cli = cliente.FetchUsingPK(id);
        return View(cliente);
    } */

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo funcionando perfeito aqui.

Comment: @YehudiMikhael, caso a resposta do colega tenha resolvido a sua questão, você pode encerrar o post dele e não se esqueça de dar um voto à resposta, caso ainda não tenha feito.

Comment: Sabe me dizer como eu fecho e dou um voto a resposta ?

Comment: @YehudiMikhael [O ideal é você fazer o Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). De qualquer forma, logo abaixo da pontuação tem um ícone em forma de "V" que serve pra você aceitar a resposta. Para dar votos, basta clicar na seta acima da pontuação da resposta. Qualquer coisa é só me chamar.